# get present year value to string

Tags: java, calendar, operating-system, date-format

I need to get the present year value in string so I did:

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
DateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");
String year = date.format(now);
```

It works on ubuntu but it's not working on windows 7.

Do you know why?
Is there a safer way to do that?

Thanks

Comment: What does "not working" mean exactly?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can simple get the year from `Calendar` instance using [`Calendar#get(int field)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#get%28int%29) method:

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
int year = now.get(Calendar.YEAR);
String yearInString = String.valueOf(year);
```

Answer (score 14):

```
String thisYear = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy").format(new Date());
```

Comment: You should probably explain a bit.

Comment: I use this. SimpleDateFormat uses Calendar. Format examples: [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 4):

In Java 8 there's a collection called [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) in which you easily can obtain the current year from your computer's clock.

To get the current year as an integer you can simply write:

```
int thisYear = Year.now().getValue();
```

To get it as a String:

```
String thisYear = Year.now().toString();
```

Answer (score 2):

What about

```
Date currentDate = new Date();
String currentYear = String.valueOf(currentDate.getYear());
```

Comment: `Date#getYear()` is deprecated.

Comment: Also, that's `year-1900`.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it like this:

```
String year = String.valueOf(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR));
```

Answer (score 2):

Java 8:

```
java.time.Year.now();
```

here is the [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Year.html).

Answer (score 1):

try

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
String year = String.valueOf(now.get(Calendar.YEAR));
```

Answer (score 1):

## Time Zone

Both the question and accepted answer ignore the question of time zone. At the time of a new year, the year number varies depending on your time zone.

## Joda-Time

The bundled java.util.Date and .Calendar classes are notoriously troublesome. Avoid them. Use either Joda-Time or the new java.time package in Java 8.

Example in Joda-Time.

```
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Paris" );
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.now( timeZone );
int year = dateTime.year().get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  //  enter code here
Date date = new Date();
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");
String year = format.format(date);
```

Comment: This is a low quality answer. You don't describe how this helps solve the issue, the answer is just code that is almost identical to what the original OP has and doesn't explain how this solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In Java versions prior Java 8 you could also use java.sql.Date class. Convert to String and substring the year:

```
String currentYear = new java.sql.Date(System.currentTimeMillis()).toString().substring(0, 4);
```